# How to get ID of user set default keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to make a button in my custom keyboard that when pressed will switch the keyboard to the default user keyboard. I have figured out how to set the input keyboard like this:

```
final String LATIN = "com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME";
final IBinder token = this.getWindow().getWindow().getAttributes().token;
imm.setInputMethod(token, LATIN);
```

In this case, pressing the button that I want to implement would switch the keyboard to the default user specified keyboard (LATIN keyboard).

The problem is in this particular example the string was already given.

How would I find the string of the ID of the default user specified keyboard so that I can set  the `InputMethod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get currently active keyboard's id like in the following example:

```
String id = Settings.Secure.getString(
                getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD)
```

If your soft keyboard is currently being used for input, the above code will return your keyboard's id.

But, you can do something like this:
When your input picker button is clicked, you can show the list of Input Methods, and let the user choose whatever Input Method  he likes:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

The above code will open a system dialog where Input Method can be picked.
Also, you can get the list of Input Methods like in the code below:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        List<InputMethodInfo> mInputMethodProperties = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();

        final int n = mInputMethodProperties.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            InputMethodInfo imi = mInputMethodProperties.get(i);
Log.d("TAG", "Input Method ID: "+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName(); }
```